# Redirect from newform to editform including the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I need to redirect users that create an item in the NewForm.aspx to the EditForm.aspx. But in order for the EditForm to be the correct one, I believe it needs the ID of the item that was just created.

How do I redirect to an EditForm, with the item ID, once the NewForm is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this. One workaround is to get Id of the most recent item and redirect user to it's edit form. You can finf more detailed description here http://www.sharepointdrive.com/blog/redirect-from-newform-aspx-to-dispform-aspx-or-editform-aspx-of-newly-created-item/